# Share Dialog from Facebook SDK appears as soon as the app loads

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on implementing the Facebook SDK for my app. My problem is that the Share Dialog appears as soon as the app finishes loading. I want the ShareDialog to only appear when the button is pressed, it does this. But again, I don't want it to appear immediately, this can get very annoying.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CallbackManager callbackManager;
ShareDialog shareDialog;
ShareLinkContent linkContent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentDescription(
                        "")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/globalwidemusiccom-116137701783410/"))
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }

    ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_share_button);
    shareButton.setShareContent(linkContent);

    LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
    likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
            "https://www.facebook.com/globalwidemusiccom-116137701783410/",
            LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://globalwidemusic.com/AppGlobalWideMusic/index.html");

    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-8679652085375496~2353468367");

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    //new global wide music
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}



}
```

I am sorry there is so much, I am not sure what to do, I have tried displaying the ShareDialog with onClick, but then it did not display at all. Any tips or code would help greatly. Thank you.

Sincerely,
Alex

Comment: I suggest you learn about the Activity lifecycle and event handling.

Comment: " I have tried displaying the ShareDialog with onClick" Please show the code where you tried this. It is closer to being correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `shareDialog.show(linkContent);` from your `onCreate()` and place it in your `onClick()`.

Comment: Thanks 323go, your solution worked. You can check out the app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=www.globalwidemusic.com&hl=en